# Passing QML events to C++ or VTK

Tags: qml, vtk

How do I pass QML events to C++ code? I want to manage these events by passing them to a VTK interactor.

Answer (score 0):

In QML code:

```
// some shape
Rectangle {    
    signal signalEvent333

    onYourEvent: {
        signalEvent333();
    }
```

And in C++ code:

```
auto* qqView = new QQuickView(); // don't forget to delete sometimes
qqView->setSource(QUrl(QStringLiteral("qrc:///res/qml/myQmlForm.qml"))); // if that qml form in the app resource
QQuickItem* root = qqView->rootObject();
connect((QObject*)root, SIGNAL(signalEvent333()), this, SLOT(onSignalEvent333()));
```

We assume we have onSignalEvent333 slot for 'this' object.

P.S. And this question should be marked Qt as well. And I don't know what VTK is.

Comment: Thanks for your response. Can I pass parameter, QMouseEvent *event, to onSignalEvent333()?

Comment: You are signaling from QML and there is obviously a lack of native Qt types there but you can definitely try to pass something, say, integer or string.

Comment: I tried passing a "mouse" event which gets interpreted as a QObject *event in a C++ function. Now I'm trying to cast the event to QMouseEvent so I can process it but I get a segmentation fault when I do a const QEvent::type t = event->type(); If I can pass the event and extract it's type and other properties, it would be a step towards passing these to VTK another API. Any comments are welcome.

Comment: try to do qDebug() << event and see what it prints out. You can only use what's in there and luckily it should have that meta information as long as it is QObject-based.

Comment: qDebug gives me QQuickMouseEvent followed by the address. When I cast it to QMouseEvent *, qDebug gives me QEvent. Yet, when I try to get the event type, it seg faults, perhaps because QQuickMouseEvent is implicitly private.

Comment: Don't do an incorrect cast. Maybe explore qobject_cast but mainly out of curiosity. qobject_cast may help if there is such instance there. Somewhat relative topic: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23282488/propagate-qml-events-to-c

Comment: I tried qobject_cast but it is not allowed to cast a QEvent* type. The post you sent a link to unfortunately does not result in a valid solution. In fact the error with passing QEvent * is Unknown method parameter type:QEvent*. Therefore the workaround with QObject*, which works until the point you try to access the event's function calls.

Comment: Just signal with your own data.

Comment: This worked with adding the eventFilter function. I can qml events on my own with the eventFilter override.